# What kind of model can i use to forecast this data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, models, data-science

This is the dataset that I have of some orders each week. I want to predict the orders for the rest of the year. I've tried building an ARIMA model and it doesn't work.

Is there any other model that I can try for such a small dataset? Maybe a HMM or try fitting a polynomial curve to it or build a time series LSTM?

`FW  Order
1      6
2     45
3     59
4     60
5     50
6    115
7     23
8     44
9    164
10      8
11     30
12     20
13      0
14     50
15     60
16      0
17     50
18     30
19    115
20     75
21     54
22     29
23    124
24     32
25     28`

Comment: How about a normal support vector regression model with polynomial kernel?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here's a plot of your data.  Your main problem is that there isn't really enough data for any model to give you meaningful predictions with statistical significance.  Your data mostly just looks like white noise around a mean, so you'd represent it with:

x_t = mu + e

where e is an error term representing white noise.

There is a hint of mean reversion, so you could try an Ornstein Uhlenbeck model:

dx_t = theta * (mu - x_t-1) dt + sigma * dW_t

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process

Here's it coded up.  Orange line is the prediction.  Again, the prediction isn't great, but you probably won't find much better without more data.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm

def least_squares_naive(s, delta=1.0):
    y = s.diff().iloc[1:]
    x = s.shift(1)[1:]

    res = sm.OLS(y, sm.add_constant(x)).fit()
    b, a = res.params

    residual_df = y - (a * x + b)
    se = residual_df.std(ddof=2)

    lambda_ = -a / delta
    mu_ = b / (lambda_ * delta)
    sigma_ = se / (delta ** 0.5)

    return mu_, lambda_, sigma_

list = [6,45,59,60,50,115,23,44,164,8,30,20,0,50,60,0,50,30,115,75,54,29,124,32,28]
s = pd.Series(list)

mu_, lambda_, sigma_ = least_squares_naive(s)

dx = -lambda_ * (s - mu_)
pred = (s + dx).shift()
diff = s.diff(1).dropna()

s.plot()
pred.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]